Quotients in the radical series of the lower triangular matrices
I have begun reading chapter 1 of Alperin's Local Representation Theory. I had a doubt in exercise 2 on page 7.
Let $T_n(k)$ be the set of lower triangular matrices of order $n×n$, $k$ is a field, and let us consider it as $T_n(k)-$module. The radical of $A-$ algebra is defined as the set of elements of $A$ that annihilate every semisimple $A-$ module. Here the radical is $N$ comprising of the lower triangular matrices with all diagonal entries 0.
Let $M_i$ be the submodule of $T_n(k)$ that comprise matrices with 0 in the $i$th entry of the diagonal. Let $S_i = T_n(k)/M_i$. It is easy to check that $T_n(k)/N = \oplus_{i=1}^n S_i$.
I now need to show that for all $i \in \{0,1, \cdots, n-1\}$, we have
$N^i/N^{i+1} \cong S_{i+1} \oplus \cdots \oplus S_n$.
We can immediately see that when such $i \geq 1, N^i \cong T_{n-i}(k)$, and $N^{i+1} \cong$ radical of $T_{n-i}(k)$. If we consider $\tilde{S_j} = T_{n-i}(k)/\tilde{M_j}$ where $\tilde{M_j}$ is the submodule of $T_{n-i}(k)$- module $T_{n-i}(k)$ with $j$th entry of diagonal 0, then we get
$N^i/N^{i+1} \cong \tilde{S_{1}} \oplus \cdots \tilde{\oplus S_{n-i}}$. Now I wish to show that for all $j \in \{1, \cdots, n-i\},$ we have $\tilde{S_j} \cong S_{i+j}$ as per our previous notation. It does seem intuitively clear why, but I cannot figure out the language to formally write it out. Is my idea alright so far?
